# Can not locate errors in eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse

After making a series of edits to a previously working android project in eclipse, I attempted to run the app and got a message `"Your project contains errors, please fix them before running your application."` Normally under these circumstances there are either some red marks next to the offending file(s), and/or text descriptions of errors listed in eclipse's "Problems" tab. But this time there are no red marks to be seen anywhere, and the errors I see described in the "problems" tab refer to files that (as far as I can tell) have nothing to do with my project.

I noticed that at the top of my list of problems it says "Errors (100 of 192 items)... I am wondering if perhaps I am being shown 100 problems from *other* projects (I have many on the go at the same time) and my critical error is one of the 92 remaining which I'm not being shown... I'm stuck as to how to proceed.

Comment: Close the projects you don't care about and do a clean build.

Comment: I'd never heard of the concept of "closing" a project before (I thought there was only delete). But I've done it and it works a treat. Put it as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: To answer your other question, Yes, it will find problems in any open projects.

Comment: The local menu of the `Problems View` can be used to `Configure Contents`--including whether you want to limit it to showing 100 items or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close the projects you don't care about and do a clean build.